# How to maintain RecyclerView filter list and main list after filtered list changes?

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

I have one `ArrayList` which is populated among

> 1) Mainactivity my main datalist
>
> 2) Inside recyclerview adapter
>
> 3) filteredlist

I have a problem, when I search some string its return filtered data. I implement to update that data, but when I update that data and refresh I get new updated data. But then I remove one character from string and the old data displayed.

Like I search "*app*" my filtered data show me "*application*" and "*apple*" in RecyclerView data.

I update "*apple*" to "*applered*"
after backpressed  my RecyclerVeiw show me "*aaplication*" and "*aaplered*"
this is ok.
After I remove one character from string "*ap*" that time my `RecyclerView` show me old "*application*" and "*apple*".

That means my data not updated all list? How can I do that to update my data update to that all three lists?

Comment: Your probably messed up with reference. There will be two different List  first the complete one and second is filtered . Add your code if you need any help .

Comment: post your adapter's code

Answer (score 1):

Others might give you better advice, but I think you should extend a `ViewModel` (or if context is required, `AndroidViewModel`) by your viewmodel class. In this class you can code your search algorithm.

You can use `LiveData` and `MutableLiveData` for this. Have a list of all the items, and add to your `MutableLiveData` your items which match the search. When you delete a character from the search string, you redo the search and add all found items into the `MutableLiveData`.

Finally, observe changes in the LiveData, and when it is changed update your adapter.

Edit for the example:

ViewModel class

```
public class MyModelSupplier extends AndroidViewModel{

//if you do not need application or context in your coustructor, class can extend ViewModel

private MutableLiveData<List<MyModel>> myModelList;
private List<myModel> nonVisibleMyModelList;
private Context context;

//Constructor
//if you do not need application or context in your coustructor, class can extend ViewModel
public MyModelSupplier(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    this.context = application.getApplicationContext();
    updateFullList();
}

LiveData<List<MyModel>> getMyModelList() {
    //this stuff is the one observed by the activity
    if (MyModelList == null) {
        MyModelList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        updateFullList();
    }
    return MyModelList;
} 

void searchMyModelListByName(final String itemName) {

    if (itemName == null) {
        MyModelList.setValue(nonVisibleMyModelList);
    } else {
        new ApplicationFilterQueryTask(searchString).execute();
    }

}


//update
private void updateFullList() { new fullListQueryTask().execute(); }
class fullListQueryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<MyModel> > {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MyModel> myRetrievedModelObjects) {
        MyModelList.setValue(myRetrievedModelObjects);
        nonVisibleMyModelList = myRetrievedModelObjects;
        super.onPostExecute(myRetrievedModelObjects);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<MyModel> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        List<MyModel> myHiddenButFoundModelObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        //gather all your stuff in here (full list))

        //return stuff in alphabetical order
        java.util.Collections.sort(installedPackages, new MyModelNameComparator());
        return installedPackages;
    }
}

//so that they can be sorted
protected class MyModelNameComparator implements Comparator<MyModel> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyModel o1, MyModel o2) {
        //getName() should be implemented in your MyModel
        return accentedToAsci(o1.getName()).compareToIgnoreCase(accentedToAsci(o2.getName()));
    }
}


class ApplicationFilterQueryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<MyModel> > {

    private final String searchString;

    ApplicationFilterQueryTask(String searchString) { this.searchString = searchString;}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MyModel> myFilteredModelList) {
        MyModelList.setValue(myFilteredModelList);
        super.onPostExecute(myFilteredModelList);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<MyModel> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        List<MyModel> searchResult = new ArrayList<>();

        //this is where the filtering occurs
        for (MyModel model : nonVisibleMyModelList) {
            if (accentedToAsci(model.getName().toLowerCase()).contains(accentedToAsci(searchString).toLowerCase())) {
                searchResult.add(model);
            }
        }

        return searchResult;
    }
}
```

}

in the main activity OnCreate, you do all your normal stuff, but populate the recyclerView like this:

```
MyModelSupplier  = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyModelSupplier.class);
    MyModelSupplier .getMyModelList().observe(this, packageSummaryList -> {

        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(// stuff here for the constructor, or you can update the old one as well);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    });
```

Your Mainactivity should extend

```
AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
```

And you should implement the methods like this (note that you need the menu resource to have the button - google this if you don't know how to add menu resource)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.menu_search_tooltip));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    MyModelSupplier.searchMyModelListByName(newText);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivitySettings.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also, this code might warn you of memory leaks, but I haven't quite figured out how to run context-related stuff in asynctask without this warning.

Let me know if you're stuck or succeeded with this.